# Isolate first and last letter in JS Word Search code

Tags: javascript, function

I am trying to build a WordSearch game; I'd like to use this Github repo:

https://github.com/bunkat/wordfind

I am not very good with JavaScript and I was wondering if anyone with more chops than me could take a look at this well formatted code on GitHub and say whether they can see how I can modify it.

I would like to add a class or attribute to the first and last letter of a word, in order that I can style it with CSS to have rounded corners?

Doesn't matter if it's when generating the grid, or when selecting a correct answer.

I hope you have some advice. Many thanks in advance.

Just a point in the right direction would be a big help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the example here : http://bunkat.github.io/wordfind/example/index.html

After finding a word - the class of each letter from the found word goes from `puzzleSquare` to `puzzleSquare found`

You could add a javascript function that will find all the `puzzleSquare found` that are next to each other. Then you add a class to the first and last element of this array

Comment: SOLUTION: Added `$('.selected').first().addClass('first ' + curOrientation)` and `$('.selected').last().addClass('last ' + curOrientation)` after line 222 of wordfindgame.js to add classes "first" and "last" as well as the orientation as a class in order to then style in CSS.